# Hiding navigation bar like in Facebook app?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am trying to hide the navigation bar like in the Facebook app.

```
navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true
```

works but it hides the nav bar using a swipe motion which doesnt feel that smooth.

I have also tried to use `self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)` when scrolling up/down to true/false. Same thing there it doesnt feel that smooth.

So how is Facebook doing this in their app? The hiding of the navigation bar feels really synced to the scroll motion. I have also tried this using constraints but I cant get it to work.

Comment: You can try this 
https://github.com/andreamazz/AMScrollingNavbar

Comment: put it in animateWithDuration block and try?

Comment: @RayChen I have already looked at that one. But I have a hard to trying to convert it into swift

Comment: @sriramhegde thanks I will give it a try now

Comment: okay but im not sure though . Good Luck

Comment: @user2722667, here is swift version https://github.com/telly/TLYShyNavBar which you can refer. And if feel not smooth, I think you'd better to review your scroll view content.